# Issue with using a for loop to install packages with specific version? R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
pckgs_needed <- data.frame("package" = c("qwraps2", "arm", "psych", "caret"),
                           "version" = c("0.4.2", "1.11-1", "1.9.12.31", "6.0-86"))
```

I'm trying to use a for loop to install these packages through the `remotes::install.packages()` command.

Although it looks like my loop is not working properly.

```
for(i in pckgs_needed$package){
  for(j in pckgs_needed$version) {
    install_version(i, version = j, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
    
  }
}
```

My goal is too essentially pass the matching package and version though the loop and install the version of the package needed.

Although it looks like its trying to install each package by each version in the dataframe based off the error I am receiving `Error in download_version_url(package, version, repos, type) :  version '1.11-1' is invalid for package 'qwraps2'` and based off this second loop

```
for(i in pckgs_needed$package){
  for(j in pckgs_needed$version) {
    print(paste(i," ", j))
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not use nested for loops. You are iterating two vectors respectively, and you are not looking at all possible pairs between package and versions.

Comment: What do you recommend? The `remotes::install_version()` function only allows for 1 input in the package & version arguments

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the function respectively instead of creating all possible pairs of package name and versions as it would be archived using nested for loops:

```
mapply(function(x, y) remotes::install_version(package = x, version = y), 
  pckgs_needed$package, pckgs_needed$version)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `versions` r package as well and pass a vector to packages and version instead of looping. However, this only works if the package you want was after 2014-09-17 when MRAN was launched.

```
library(versions)
install.versions(pkgs = pckgs_needed$package, version = pckgs_needed$version)
```